# PDF reader with highlighting and bookmarks

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, ebook-reader

Is there any way to read PDF books with highlighting texts and adding custom bookmarks?

I would like to read a book having about 500 and more pages and I would like to highlight sentences and words and then create bookmarks for these pages in order to find them later without need to list through the entire book. If it could read docx as well it would be great. I don't mind if it is paid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Adobe Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en) to highlight your text while you read and add bookmarks.

There is an app called [iAnnotate PDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.branchfire.iannotate&hl=en) as well. But it seems tat the bookmarking frature is not available for this APP.

Comment: And where exactly can I in AR add custom bookmarks? I only found a menu where are bookmarked all book chapters.